# REST API: Can nested URI co-exist with lookup by ID?

Tags: rest, http

Suppose I have a collection of "Orders".

(a) Orders are divided into three categories: "pending", "confirmed", "completed".

(b) Naturally, orders can be looked up by ID

Initially I thought of this URI scheme:

For (a):

- `GET /orders/:id`

For (b):

- `GET /orders/pending`
- `GET /orders/confirmed`
- `GET /orders/completed`

The problem with this approach is that there is a (very very rare) chance that an order will receive the ID "pending" (or "confirmed" or "completed"), in which case the URI `/orders/pending` becomes ill-defined.

The other alternative is to use: `GET /orders_pending` but this seems less elegant.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

A solution that immediately came to mind was to use

```
GET /orders?category=pending HTTP/1.1
```

This works with a query and should be easy to implement on any server.

Resource's properties should not be used as url segments because ideally, every url segment represents a resource (or multiple), not a property. I think you already know that because you said it yourself

> The problem with this approach is that there is a (very very rare)
>   chance that an order will receive the ID "pending" (or "confirmed" or
>   "completed"), **in which case the URI /orders/pending becomes
>   ill-defined**.

If you want to filter results based on the value of a property, using a query in the url is the way to go.

Also, as @mahemoff pointed out

> It's possible to build on this, e.g. ?category=pending&paid=true, and
>   you can't really extend /orders/pending style of URL to cover all
>   possible query inputs.

Comment: This is a good answer because the requirement is a search/filter on simply `/orders`, being the list of all orders. It's possible to build on this, e.g. ?category=pending&paid=true and you can't really extend /orders/pending style of URL to cover all possible query inputs.